# chat application using jsp and servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, chat

I am developing chat appliction using jsp and servlets. Can anyone tell me, what are the possiblities to notify the administrator (trigger events in administrator account), when the client hits the "Startchat " button?

Comment: dozens. depending on whether you need the administrator to have a browser window open or if you can afford having a desktop client, or an applet.

Comment: I've done a simple project with respect to JSP Chat [JSP Practice: Simple chat](http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2012/01/jsp-practice-simple-chat.html)

Answer (score 4):

Just let the button fire a HTTP request to the server side which in turn invokes the `Servlet` associated with the `url-pattern` of the particular HTTP request. The request can be fired either synchronously with a simple link or form:

```
<form action="servletUrl">
    <input type="submit" value="Startchat">
</form>
```

...or asynchronously with help of a shot of JavaScript/Ajax. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is of great help here:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    $.get('servletUrl', function() {
        // Callback here.
    });
});

...

<button id="buttonId">Startchat</button>
```

Finally in the `Servlet` associated with the `url-pattern` of `/servletUrl` just do the desired task to notify the administrator. As you didn't tell in what way you'd like to notify the administrator (there are dozens, as Bozho stated in a comment), I'll only give a trivial kickoff example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    notifyAdministratorAbout(request);

    if (not requested by ajax) {
        request.setAttribute("start", true);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("chat.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DWR might offer a [solution](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/reverse-ajax/index.html) for use in webapp. for other solutions, you can search google for 'java' and 'comet'